# Track of account records into alternate contact (custom object) records

Tags: trigger, after-trigger

We need to track any change in billing Address ( address,city,state,zip)  of Account in a new Object : ÄLTERNATE CONTACT  (Address, City,State, Zip, UpdatedDateTime, Account) .  This object should only store unique address information. If the same address already exists in Alternate contact, just update “UpdatedDateTime” field without creating a new record.Only required on after update trigger

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: it seems that you know what to do, a trigger on account after update, so I'll ask the same as Mr.Frodo : what problem are you facing ? What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd put something like this in the trigger :

```
List<Id> ids = new List<Id>(); //ids of accounts with watched fields modified
for (Integer i=0; i<trigger.new.size(); i++) //foreach account
{
  if ( //if one of your fields is modified
       (trigger.old[i].address != trigger.new[i].address) || 
       (trigger.old[i].Zip != trigger.new[i].Zip) // || etc. with all field u want
     )
     {
        ids.add(trigger.new[i].Id); //keep track of its id
     }
}
if (ids.size()>0) //if u got accounts modified
{
  AlternateContact__c[] altCts = [Select Id, UpdatedDateTime__c from AlternateContact__c where AccountId__c in :ids]; //select alt contacts linked to these accounts
  for (AlternateContact__c ac : altCts) { //for each of them 
    ac.UpdatedDateTime__c = DateTime.now(); //update the date
  }
  update altCts; //save your changes
}
```

Please have a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help before you post your next question. This one lacked details.

**Edit** after your comment : 
If I understood you need to

1. Query all fields on your AlternateContact__c object related to account
2. Check if all the fields (except id of course) match your new address
3. if it does update date
4. if it doesn't create new AlternateContact__c

I can see nothing hard in it, you just have to adapt the code I wrote up there.

Comment: Actually, I want to write a trigger on account object so that when account's address is updated with a new address then its old address record is created in alternate contact object. But when the account address is updated with any of the previously created alternate contact address records then the UpdatedDateTime__c field of that alternate contact record will be updated with the current time without creating any new alternate contact record. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First I would'nt call "contact" an object supposed to represent an address since contact is already a totally different object in Salesforce.

Comment: alternate contact(alternate_contact__c) is a custom child object of account.

Comment: yes I got it, as you can see if you look at the code (and understand it) I wrote. If my answers are not enough I'm afraid you should start with learning https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm  or https://trailhead.salesforce.com/ : I can't do more or I'd have to bill you ;)